# Remove null character embedded in string

Tags: c++, string, null-character

I have a c++ `string` with embedded `'\0'` characters.

I have a function `replaceAll()` which *should* replace all occurrences of a pattern with another pattern. For "normal" strings it works fine. However, when I try to find the `'\0'` character my function does not work and I don't know why. `replaceAll` seems to be failing on `string::find()` which doesn't make sense to me.

```
// Replaces all occurrences of the text 'from' to the text 'to' in the specified input string.
// replaceAll("Foo123Foo", "Foo", "Bar"); // Bar123Bar
string replaceAll( string in, string from, string to )
{
    string tmp = in;

    if ( from.empty())
    {
    return in;
    }

    size_t start_pos = 0;

    // tmp.find() fails to match on "\0"
    while (( start_pos = tmp.find( from, start_pos )) != std::string::npos )
    {
    tmp.replace( start_pos, from.length(), to );
        start_pos += to.length(); // In case 'to' contains 'from', like replacing 'x' with 'yx'
    }

    return tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string stringWithNull = { '\0', '1', '\0', '2' };
    printf("size=[%d] data=[%s]\n", stringWithNull.size(), stringWithNull.c_str());

    // This doesn't work in the special case of a null character and I don't know why
    string replaced = replaceAll(stringWithNull, "\0", "");
    printf("size=[%d] data=[%s]\n", replaced.size(), replaced.c_str());
}
```

Output:

```
size=[4] data=[]
size=[4] data=[]
```

Comment: Did you debug it to see if your loop was really finding the character?

Comment: BTW, you should actually search for the characters themselves, not strings.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Why search for the characters?  That limits the function.  If I want to reaplce all occurances of `":)"` from `":) :) :) :::too many smiles::: :) :) :)"` that would be a real pain if I couldn't specify `":)"` as the thing to replace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work in your case is that `std::string` constructor from `const char*` without size is going to read all elements up to, but not including nul-terminating char. As a result,

```
 replaceAll(stringWithNull, "\0", "");
```

Calls `replaceAll` with `from` set to empty string (`replaceAll( string in, string from, string to )`), which returns `in` unmodified.

To solve the problem, use a constructor which takes size, or initialize with  list initialization, the same way you do it for your original string, for example:

```
replaceAll(stringWithNull, {'\0'}, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
replaceAll(stringWithNull, "\0", "");
```

`"\0"` is the same as `""` since `std::string`'s constructor stops at the null character when being constructed from a c-string.  That means you are searching for nothing and replacing it with nothing.  What you need is

```
string replaced = replaceAll(stringWithNull, {'\0'}, "");
```

to actually get `from` populated with a null character.